# Problem with graphic device on binary-driver notebook

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

on my notebook I have two graphical device. AMD HD6470M and AMD M880G with ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4250. Ubuntu automatically select the second graphical card, but it isn't so powerfull as I want.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250] [1002:9712] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

I tryed to select HD6470M in Ubuntu 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, but result was the same: System is running in low-graphic mode. Recently I found out, that driver fglrx used in these version don't support Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series.
My process:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

but:

```
root@Vojta-PC:/home/vojta# sudo amdconfig --initial -f
amdconfig: No supported adapters detected
root@Vojta-PC:/home/vojta# sudo amdconfig --px-dgpu
amdconfig: No supported adapters detected
```

I got advice to try Unutnu 12.04.1. Driver fglrx used in this version allegedly support Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series.
My process:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
sudo amdconfig --px-dgpu
```

But result was that screen of Ubuntu stayed purpure. It was all. I have heart login sound even, but nothing to seen.
[X.org log here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzO1nkmWvksgUVVPZTdlSko0TVU/edit?usp=sharing)
Do you know, how to solve it. Thanks.